type null is not a subtype of string while run active ecommerce app
i'm trying to customize active ecommerce flutter app. i have followed instruction by active ecommerce documentation. but there is an error in my app. here is the screenshort given bellowtype null is not a subtype of string 
while i run the project it show this error
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_messaging-14.7.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
how to resolve this.
